# How to check if a unittest.mock.Mock has return_value set?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have a [`unittest.mock.Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) instance `m`. The only thing I know is that it mocks a class with a `foo()` method. I need to determine whether `m.foo.return_value` has been set and if not, provide a default value. Is this possible?

In other words, how to implement `has_return_value_set()` below?

```
m = unittest.mock.Mock()
# ...
if not has_return_value_set(m.foo):
    m.foo.return_value = MY_RETURN_VALUE
```

I have tried checking `m.foo.return_value` directly, but it is initialized to a new mock upon the first access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you haven't actually accessed `mock.return_value` yet, you can test if a non-standard return value has been set with:

```
m.foo._mock_return_value is unittest.mock.DEFAULT
```

The moment you use the `mock.return_value` property, if `mock._mock_return_value` is set to `unittest.mock.DEFAULT` still, a new `Mock` instance is created and stored in `mock._mock_return_value` for future re-use.

Note that this attribute is an implementation detail, which is why it starts with an underscore. It is not documented and may change in a future release. However, there currently is no other method to check if `mock.return_value` has been set explicitly.